# Codeigniter add attribute to open_form_multipart

Tags: php, database, forms, codeigniter

We have a form that adds products to our database. We have here in a `open_form_multipart` for the images. We think that the problem is that it doesn't add our attributes.

error:

> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'product_foto' cannot be null
>
> INSERT INTO `products` (`product_naam`, `product_beschrijving`, `product_categorie`, `ophaal_plaats`, `product_foto`, `date_created`, `date_updated`) VALUES ('', '', '', '', NULL, '2017-06-20', '2017-06-20')
>
> Filename: models/Product_model.php
>
> Line Number: 9

our code is in the view:

```
<?php
echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');
echo form_open_multipart('name="product_foto"');
echo form_upload('file');
echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow conventions for defining form.

[Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Your code should be:

```
$arr = array('name' => 'product_foto');
echo form_open_multipart('', $arr);
```

> form_open_multipart([$action = ''[, $attributes = array()[, $hidden =
> array()]]])
>
> Parameters:
>
> $action (string) – Form action/target URI
>
> string $attributes (array) – HTML attributes
>
> $hidden (array) – An
> array of hidden fields’ definitions Returns:   An HTML multipart form
> opening tag
>
> Return type:   string

**Note:** Action is set blank so that the the form will submit to the same page.